# I can't get Axios post information

Tags: reactjs

For my posts.
In component AboutUsers.jsx.

```java
   const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

If I write like this, it's working, I see posts in users.

in component AboutUsers.jsx

```java
    useEffect(()=> {
        const getUsers = 
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',{
            params:{
                _limit:limitPage,
                _page:currentPage
            }
        })
            .then(response => setUsers(response.data))
    },[])
```

But I created other component PostMyServise.js with:

```java
    export default class PostMyServise {
        static async getPost(limit=10, page=1) {
            const result  = await 
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',{
                params: {
                    _limit: limit,
                    _page: page,
                }
        })
                .then(response => {
                    return response
                })
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And one yet component useCreatePosts.js:

```java
    export const usePosts = (callback) => {
       const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState('')
       const [error, setError] = useState('')

       const createPost = async () => {
           try {
               setIsTrue(false);
               await callback;
           } catch (e) {
                   setError(e.message);
           } finally {
                   setIsTrue(true);
           }
       }
    return [createPost, isTrue, error];
    }

    export default usePosts;
```

I wrote this, and I see empty array in console.log(users):
I don't understand why array is empty

```java
    const [createPost, isTrue, error] = usePosts (async ()=> {
    const response = await PostMyServise.getPost(limitPage, currentPage);
        setUsers(response.data)
    })

    useEffect(() => {
            createPost();
    },[currentPage])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the `callback`. You need to add the parentheses.

```
   const createPost = async () => {
       try {
           setIsTrue(false);
           await callback();
       } catch (e) {
               setError(e.message);
       } finally {
               setIsTrue(true);
       }
   }
```

I feel like something about your code is over-engineered and too complex but that's outside the scope of the question. This change will at least get it working. Also, I suggest changing the name of `isTrue` and `setIsTrue` to something more meaningful as those names do not tell you what they are for.